# Intellij code style to align single-line comments

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, formatting

Right now IntelliJ's autoformat changes this:

```
    val reduceFn = (left: U, right: U) => {
      left ++ right                         // comment 1
              .myFuncA( _._1 )              // comment 2
              .myFuncABC {                  // comment 3
                g => {                      // comment 4
                  g.myFun                   
                  ._2                       
                  .myFunBBB( 0 )( _ + _ )   
                }
              }
    }: U                                    // comment 5
```

to this:

```
    val reduceFn = (left: U, right: U) => {
      left ++ right // comment 1
              .myFuncA( _._1 ) // comment 2
              .myFuncABC {
                // comment 3
                g => {
                  // comment 4
                  g.myFun 
                  ._2 
                  .myFunBBB( 0 )( _ + _ ) 
                }
              }
    }: U // comment 5
```

Is there a way I can tell IntelliJ to produce, or, at the very least, not clobber the former style? I don't see comments as an option in Code Style in Editor > Code Style > Scala:

[image]

Comment: You have almost 2000 reputation, please learn how this site works. [Stack snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are for Javascript.

Comment: Also, why on earth do you want those comments - why do you want to annotate each line with the type. That is the whole reason you use an IDE, so that it can work out types for you... Personally I think they serve no purpose except to make the code illegible.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Aligned trailing comments are sometimes appropriate, but that is off-topic; this question is about how to configure IntelliJ to achieve a particular format, not about best practices in code clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is supported at the moment. There's a ticket for it ([SCL-4269](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4269)), but as of writing there has not been any real activity on it.

You can completely disable the formatter for certain lines by using the formatter control option (cf. Code Style preference page). But that's obviously not a good solution.